# Can I create password protected folder in Android?

Tags: android, password-protection

I would like to create a folder which is password protected. I am able to create a folder in the following way, but how can I create a password protected folder?

```
File nf = new File("/sdcard/NewFolder");
nf.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 5):

- in android there is not possible but we can hide using "." at prefix
- otherwise Store important folder or file in internal memory.
- you can see you package directory following way
          String dir = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.kinkey", 0).applicationInfo.dataDir;

Note: it is visible on windows pc

Comment: There are lot of application on play store that add the password to folder. If it is not possible then how these are working.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create such a folder on sdcard. Everything that's saved onto sdcard can be accessed by other applications. If you want to create a folder which is not accessible from outside of your application use [Context.getDir()](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method with mode set to [MODE_PRIVATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE):

```
Context ctx = getContext();
File folder = ctx.getDir("NewFolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: thanks for reply..but when I use this function in code its giving result as unexpectedly program stopped.  
What to do could you please tell me if need to give any permissions in manifest.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
I have given above permissions to my manifest.
thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know writing to internal app directory doesn't requires any permissions. Can you post a logcat error log with a stack trace to identify you problem?

Comment: is it possible to use folder for two or three application , not for rest of the other. I'm creating an app in which i save the image pro grammatically  but i want to make that folder accessible for ms-word and image viewer not  for other.