# How to redirect User from Gallery TO my application in ANdroid?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

When user taps gallery button I want user to redirect to my application's activity which will ask the user to enter password and then redirect user back to gallery ..
I want to know which permissions should i use and which broadcast should i accept .

Comment: What I am DOing will take 3 weeks I am getting data using mediaScanner and encrypting that data using my application ....What I want to do is make a Gallery Lock APpplication Like Free Gallery Lock On Play.google...in simple words What i want to do is when i press the lock on  button in my application ,the contents of gallery becomes hidden from the gallery and when i press the lock off button the contents of gallery become visible again in gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well If you want to lock the gallery you can do it in encrypt Decrypt way...
You can use MediaStore to access the images and then encrypt using your application and when user Again want to access that you can allow him to show by decrypting ...
Read the following link
[Can I create password protected folder in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429312/can-i-create-password-protected-folder-in-android/15022899#15022899)

Comment: It seems to be time consuming task then :(

Answer (score 1):

You would need to replace the gallery application entirely to do what you're proposing.

When a user taps the Gallery icon, it doesn't fire a broadcast. It sends a directed intent with the action set to MAIN.

Anything that anyone tells you for how to do this is going to be wrong. You cannot do it.

The closest you could get is to use the MediaStore in your own app to access the same images that the gallery accesses.

Comment: You could remove/alter the images in MediaStore which the Gallery uses. The app that you're describing is a bad idea. You should build a new app which offers protected access to a separate group of images and handles displaying them. Part of the problem is that anything that is accessible in the gallery will be accessible when the phone is plugged into a computer.

Comment: What i want to do is when i press the lock on  button in my application ,the contents of gallery becomes hidden from the gallery and when i press the lock off button the contents of gallery become visible again in gallery.

Comment: I understand what you want to do. It's a bad idea. It is extremely likely that you will be completely unable to protect the contents from plugging the phone in to a computer. Again, you could remove/alter the images in MediaStore which the Gallery uses which would do what you describe, but which is a _bad_ _idea_.

Comment: I know its bad Idea but i want to know how i can do this Can you point me to the code or Tutorial thats Important for me right now Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start a thread from your app which should periodically monitor foreground app name which in this case should be the Gallery (I cant remember the exact name But you can find it out using below logic).

Then if it is Gallery, open up your activity by blocking it.
If password success close activity & background will be the Gellery or otherwise redirect to Home.

For monitor foreground app

```
    try {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
        PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        output1 = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(runningTasks.get(0).baseActivity.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)).toString();
        String className = runningTasks.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();      

        if( className.contains("Gallery")) {

          //better to create this object globally outside the thread.           
          Intent intentSettingLock = new Intent();
          intentSettingLock.setClass(oContext,SettingsLockNew.class);
          intentSettingLock.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

          oContext.startActivity(intentSettingLock);

        }
    }   
    catch(Exception e) {        
    }
```

To redirect to home on invalid password

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);  
this.finish();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not perform this as you described because pressing the gallery app icon from the launcher the system fires an intent with action=MAIN and category=LAUNCHER for the specific application package.
Since you cannot name your application package as the gallery package name you cant filter this intent.

Comment: What i want to do is when i press the lock on  button in my application ,the contents of gallery becomes hidden from the gallery and when i press the lock off button the contents of gallery become visible again in gallery.