# can we protect the folder of SDCard in android?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I need to protect the folder in SDcard by enter the password , means when we click on the folder which should ask  the user for enter the password,if there is any code or any way for this? If so please help me Am new to android developing..

Thank you.

Comment: may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429312/can-i-create-password-protected-folder-in-android

Comment: Thanks for reply can you please tell me how to use this code in my app i cant clear with this.

Comment: Sorry i never done this before. Hope someone will see your question :)