# Can it possible to create password protected folder in Android?

Tags: android

Can I create password protected folder in Android?

```
 File nf = new File("Folder");
    nf.mkDire();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create password protected folder in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429312/can-i-create-password-protected-folder-in-android)

Comment: Yes, you just have to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

First, `new File("Folder")` has no meaning in Android. Always use some method to get at a root location, whether that is for [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) or [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Second, you cannot create a password-protected folder in Android at the OS level. You are welcome to store files in internal storage, in which case they are only accessible via your app, which can require a password (exception: people who root their devices can get at the files directly).

Comment: My required is only folder is password protected